# Issue in calling Ajax from magento

Tags: php, jquery, magento, magento-1.7

enter code here

I am new to magento.
I am trying to call Ajax from JavaScript.
I created a Module and one controller.
I enabled that module as well as controller.
My Package Name is Package and Module name is ajax.
Controller Name is AjaxController.php in controller directory of module.
function name I want to use is ViewAction with no Params.
I am echo a simple message.

So my URL becomes

```
http://216.12.194.46/~thetyrec/magento/index.php/ajax/ajax/view/

or   http://216.12.194.46/~thetyrec/magento/ajax/ajax/view/
```

I am getting 404 error in both of them.

Please guide me. Where I can be wrong or how can I debug further.

I am not seeing any such issue in var/report and log files.

Tutorial I am following is http://blog.baobaz.com/en/blog/magento-module-create-your-own-controller

**Edit :**

After more debugging I found that I am getting error

```
a:5:{i:0;s:51:"Controller file was loaded but class does not exist";i:1;s:1072:"#0 /home/thetyrec/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(326): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Controller file...')
```

when I try to access URL

```
http://216.12.194.46/~thetyrec/magento/index.php/ajax/ajax/view
```

and my code for controller is

```
class Package_Ajax_AjaxController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function viewAction()
   {

       echo "I am getting below value:";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call that ajax function of your front controller from phtml files then you can do it like this:
Create ajax function on top of the page on phtml like

```
<script>

function SubmitRequest()
{

  var values = "Your dummy value";
  new Ajax.Request('ajax/index/view/', {
  method: 'post',
  parameters: {cmb: values},
  onSuccess: successFunc()
  });

}

function successFunc(){

   return function(response){     
     var container = $("mydiv");
    var content = response.responseText;
    container.update(content);

  }

}


</script>
```

your controller function will be like that :

```
public function viewAction()
{

    echo  $_POST['cmb'];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read carefully his problem is not how to do an Ajax call, but to call his controller action in general.

I would advise to check the `<frontName>` tag inside `<frontend><routers>` in config.xml.

Then do a call to:

`http://216.12.194.46/~thetyrec/magento/index.php/CONTENT OF FRONTNAME/ajax/view`

You dont need to use Ajax to verify, just call the URL via you browser.

And by the way dont´t just echo, do something like this in your controller action:

`$this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');`

`$this->getResponse()->setBody($jsonData);`

Good luck!